# Сравнить два массива и удалить одинаковые элементы

Tags: c#

Имеется два массива:

```
string[] mods = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("mods.txt"); 
string[] mods_temp = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("mods_temp.txt");
```

Нужно найти одинаковые элементы и удалить их из обоих массивов.

Comment: А что на выходе должно получиться? Массив с уникальными элементами из обоих массивов?

Comment: На выходе в каждом массиве должны остаться его уникальные элементы

Answer (score 8):

Сначала находим пересечение последовательностей:

```
var intersect = mods.Intersect(mods_temp).ToArray();
```

Потом из каждой последовательности выбираем только элементы, отсутствующие в пересечении:

```
mods = mods.Except(intersect).ToArray();
mods_temp = mods_temp.Except(intersect).ToArray();
```

Comment: не совсем подходит под дубликат: и действия разные, и тип второй коллекции отличается от первой

Answer (score 6):

Метод [`Enumerable.Except<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var mods2 = mods.Except(mods_temp);
var mods_temp2 = mods_temp.Except(mods);
```